# DWORD datatype in VC++ nd its conversion in Java

Tags: java, c++, visual-c++

I want to convert a convert a VC++ code into Java,
Therefore which Java datatype sholud be used to replace DWORD datatype in VC++ ?

Comment: Integer probably comes very close

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `int` if you just need a 32-bit value. If you need to perform arithmetic operations or print the value you can use a `long` instead.

```
int i = /* 32-bit value */
long l = i & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
```

The long can be used as it can have values 0 to 2^32 (and more)

Comment: The long <b>should</b>/<b>better</b> be used.

Answer (score 1):

`DWORD` is a 4-byte unsigned integer. So it'd be `unsigned int` in java. Unfortunately we don't have any `unsigned` types in java, so... that'd be just `int`. Further reading: http://www.javamex.com/java_equivalents/unsigned.shtml

Comment: The code "equivalent" of unsigned int in C++ should definitely be long in Java. even the examples in your link illustrate that. The int in Java being signed does not cover the interval of possible values for an unsigned int in C++.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but if anyone else has this problem nowadays and find this question: I did a library to help me to start converting VC++ code to Java.

https://github.com/rfocosi/dotnet-types

Hope it will help someone else.